# typescript inference of generics argument of type not assignable

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I am trying to infer the `data` type in my doAction from the generic type of my `GAction`

I don't understand why I get the error message `Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`
Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

```
abstract class Action<GData> {
  abstract isValid(data : GData): boolean

  static dostuff<GData>(action: Action<GData>, data : GData): boolean {
    return action.isValid(data);
  }
}
  abstract class State<GAction extends Action<any>> {
    abstract doAction(action: GAction, data: any): State<GAction> 
  }
  
  class NextAction extends Action<string> {
    isValid(data: string): boolean {
      return (data === "222")
    }
  }
  
  class LastAction extends Action<number> {
    isValid(data : number): boolean {
      return (data === 254);
    }
  
  }
  
  type AllStateActions = LastAction | NextAction 

  type ActionData<S> = S extends Action<infer H> ? H : never;
  class OneState extends State<AllStateActions> {
    doAction<GAction extends AllStateActions, GData extends ActionData<GAction>> (action: GAction , data: GData): OneState {
      if(!action.isValid(data)) {
        return this;
      }
      return this; 
    }
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this line:

```js
type AllStateActions = LastAction | NextAction
```

Union of function never behaves in an expected way. In fact, I'm not aware of a case where you need to use union of functions.

Consider this example:

```js
type Foo = (v: { name: string }) => void

type Bar = (v: { age: number }) => void

type Union = Foo | Bar

declare const union:Union

// union(v: { name: string; } & { age: number; })
union()
```

Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

> Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred

Let's go back to our original example:

```js
type AllStateActions = LastAction | NextAction

declare const action:AllStateActions

// isValid(data: never): boolean
action.isValid()
```

`isValid` expects `never`, because `string & number === never`. Intersection of `string` and `number` is unrepresentable.

In order to fix it, you should intersection:

```js
type AllStateActions = LastAction & NextAction
```

Intersection of two function overloads them.

WHole code:

```js
abstract class Action<GData> {
    abstract isValid(data: GData): boolean

    static dostuff<GData>(action: Action<GData>, data: GData): boolean {
        return action.isValid(data);
    }
}
abstract class State<GAction extends Action<any>> {
    abstract doAction(action: GAction, data: any): State<GAction>
}

class NextAction extends Action<string> {
    isValid(data: string): boolean {
        return (data === "222")
    }
}

class LastAction extends Action<number> {
    isValid(data: number): boolean {
        return (data === 254);
    }
}

type AllStateActions = LastAction & NextAction // <-------------------------- IMPORTANT CHANGE

type ActionData<S> = S extends Action<infer H> ? H : never;

class OneState extends State<AllStateActions> {

    doAction<GAction extends AllStateActions, GData extends ActionData<GAction>>(action: GAction, data: GData): OneState {
        if (!action.isValid(data)) {
            return this;
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAggvAlgewDsAeAcQBFgJgA%20BAbwCgFmFRIZ4EcwA1YZHABMAFIMrAAXAnLiAlFJB48yAKbACDJi0iUcsBILyQArgDNTpClWrC4EfASnZ7hS%20OoAaA%20Kkyq8hEVlNQJ6LRYWKBUIYyhQuwcAOm4%20ARExfwBucIQAXwZ8tmg7JFR0BABlKggVUmcHBBUADxqCQQx613UAT2paRgiijkRDToJbXEJfMa8MyVYCboCqylqSMeoCzRQ0DAA5ZogxxpaVNo7J4nYcAgBzfpyU-iFRHwRru4Cg1XUwiIiojE4ghXlQEABeSEIABEACZ4dDZDl8vkGDtygAZNBHS4nVrtLCXIgEYwAWxAKigDwiTzSoPmJPJlK%20Sh%20oQG-2YgNioXpEKhsIArAAWWTZCIozQQboABxUWGQyBWNTGGHBCCxkGOADIEAcWscAPSGhBEAC0FstVutNutCAAkgBZAAKAHkAEoAFUwe09CAAwgAJH0kACiUtl8rGVmARAqtHVFTxZwJYyIN1MlIQgdoAH5swgpAQVAA3SnZNFlDCu4vK%20WHFMYOtETCKuuqh45UZE9a4hvnBVK6oqVVePzAZMD6PiOqXPoTFyOaQzbxUXwxgI1lR1v6crimEEAQgShGSvGe6Tksl3e8i0R5CAgAAtuOK9-lb9zgc-X8itgwgA)

Comment: Thank you, your answer sent me in the right direction!